# Navigating between fragment and activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, navigation-drawer, fragmentmanager

I been having trouble navigating between fragments and activity, i have used the Auto generated Template of **Android studios 2.2.3** and customized it to navigate between fragments.

I added five fragment and used this tutorial [Using Fragments with the Navigation Drawer Activity](http://chrisrisner.com/Using-Fragments-with-the-Navigation-Drawer-Activity).

The fragments are working perfectly and everything is all fine, so I wanted to go to another activity using the same **Navigation Drawer**  but it kept on crashing i used Intent.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_schedule) {
     fragmentClass = ScheduleFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_assingment) {
        fragmentClass = AssignmentsFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_teachers) {
        fragmentClass = TeachersFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_score) {
        fragmentClass = ScoreFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_events) {
        fragmentClass = EventsFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_setting) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
         try {
             try {
                 fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
             } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
         }catch (android.app.Fragment.InstantiationException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**Logcat**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.zer0ll.demo.studentapp, PID: 31638
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance()' on a null object reference
                      at com.zer0ll.demo.studentapp.Activities.HomeActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(HomeActivity.java:95)
                      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:156)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(SubMenuBuilder.java:88)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                      at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:342)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Add some coding part also, where and what exact error are you getting?

Comment: The issue might be you haven't defined the activity in your manifest. But still for more clarity, you need to provide crash logs and code here.

Comment: @Avi I apologise I'll edit it now

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the activity in your manifest.

Comment: My activities are working perfectly I can't call them them navigating drawer that's all.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your activity in manifest file,

```
<activity android:name="Packagename.AboutActivity">

        </activity>

    <activity android:name="Packagename.LoginActivity">

        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your Activity with Activity Context not using Application Context and return true after start activity and also declare in menifest with right package name like this

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;
    if (id == R.id.nav_schedule) {
        fragmentClass = ScheduleFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_assingment) {
        fragmentClass = AssignmentsFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_teachers) {
        fragmentClass = TeachersFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_score) {
        fragmentClass = ScoreFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_events) {
        fragmentClass = EventsFragment.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_setting) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(classname.this,AboutActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        Intent i = new Intent(classname.this,LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    try {
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }catch (android.app.Fragment.InstantiationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but nothing changed

Comment: return result true when yout start your activity, that might help you like this  Intent i = new Intent(classname.this,LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;  I already made chages ther in my answer see it